# I can't delete my own comments?

Tags: bug, comments

In [this comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/is-the-k%c4%81l%c4%81ma-sutta-really-libertarian/11356?noredirect=1#comment18642_11356) (which, may be deleted eventually) Jayarava wrote,

> Nope. It appears I cannot delete my own comments.

Comment: I cross-posted this topic to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266030/139866

Answer (score 2):

No I don't see the icon. I'm using Chrome on Vista. That a problem?

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem: I'm using Chrome on Vista too. Do you want to flag this as a bug? I've never heard of other people having this problem.

Comment: An alternative way to delete a comment might be as follows: click on the "mobile" link which is in the footer towards the bottom each page (to the left of "contact us" and above the list of all the sites) ... that shows a page layout that's optimized for mobile phones ... I think that layout has the delete link permanently visible (because there is no mouse and therefore there is no hover on a touchscreen). After using that to delete, you could then return to the non-mobile view.

Comment: Definitely seems to be a bug.

Comment: And yet you see the icons appear which let you upvote or flag someone else's comment, when you hover over someone else's comment, don't you?

Comment: yes I do see those icons.
BTW I just tried on Firefox and I still don't get the icons. Are the a popup? I have adblocker... hang on.

Comment: Nope adblocker is not the problem.

Comment: I posted [a bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266030/139866). Someone is asking you to [try something](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266030/user-doesnt-see-the-comment-delete-icon/266033#comment863186_266030) which should show whether the problem is in the interaction between your browser and the design of the site's display, alternatively whether it's in the server (which, for example, is what prevents you from deleting other people's comments). And [I posted this to explain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266033/139866) to you just how to do that test they're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the non-mobile version of the site and using a mouse, then when you use the mouse to hover over one of your own comments then the following icon should appear towards the bottom-right of the comment:

[image]

Do you not see this icon? Is your comment not deleted when you press the icon?